# Do logs get saved on Google Kubernetes

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am running a deployment which contains three containers the app, nginx and  cloud sql instance. I have a lot of print statements in my python based app.

Every time a user interacts with the app, outputs are printed. I want to know if these logs are saved by default at any location.

I am worried that these logs might consume the space on the nodes in the cluster running it. Does this happen ? or Kubernetes deployments by default don't save any logs by default?

Answer (score 1):

The applications run in containers usually under Docker and the stdout/stderr logs are saved for the lifetime of the container in the graph directory (usually `/var/lib/docker`)

You can look at the logs with either:

```
$ kubectl logs <pod-name> -c <container-in-pod>
```

Or:

```
$ ssh <node>
$ docker logs <container>
```

If you'd like to know more where they are stored you can go into the `/var/lib/docker` directory and see the logs stored in JSON format:

```
$ cd /var/lib/docker/containers
$ find . | grep json.log
./3454a0681100986248fd81856fadfe7cd95a1a6467eba32adb33da74c2c5443d/3454a0681100986248fd81856fadfe7cd95a1a6467eba32adb33da74c2c5443d-json.log
./80a87a9529a55f8d3fb9b814f0158dc91686704222e252b256455bcde48f56a5/80a87a9529a55f8d3fb9b814f0158dc91686704222e252b256455bcde48f56a5-json.log
...
```

If you'd like to do garbage collection on 'Exited' containers you can read more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/).

Another way is to set up a cron job that runs periodically on your nodes that does this:

```
$ docker system prune -a --force
```

Comment: but, what if my container is running continuously and logs are getting created when a user interacts with app in the container. How do i ensure regular clean up so that it wont fill up the node and my docker application hangs up

Comment: That's a common problem, you can ship the logs directly to another facility like an ELK stack. Maybe having a sidecar on your pod: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/.